# States where the number of suppliers exceeds the number of consumers

Tags: sql

I'm working on trying to get states where the number of suppliers is greater than the number of consumers in those states. 
Here is the code I'm tryin to get working:
[image]
When I exclude the having clause I get the following results:[image]

The code is giving me no results. Also here is a snapshot of the database diagram.[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)` instead of `count()`:

```
select s.state, count(distinct s.supp_id), count(distinct c.con_id)
```

What is happening is that you are getting a Cartesian product within each state of every supplied crossed with every consumer.

A better solution is actually to aggregate the data before joining.  But this is the simplest change to the query that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
SELECT s.state, supp_count, con_count
FROM
(SELECT s.state, COUNT(s.supp_ID) as supp_count
FROM tb_supplier s) supp
INNER JOIN
(SELECT c.state, COUNT(c.con_ID) as con_count
FROM tb_consumer c) con
ON supp.state = con.state
WHERE supp_count > con_count
```

Of course, this approach assumes (1) uniqueness in the supplier and consumer tables and (2) that each supplier in the supplier table should be counted as should each consumer in the consumer table, even if they do not exist in the transaction table, as that is not referenced.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT supp.State, supp_count "Number of Supplier", con_count "Number of Consumer"
FROM
(SELECT State, COUNT(Supp_ID) as supp_count
FROM Tb_Supplier 
GROUP BY State) supp
INNER JOIN
(SELECT State, COUNT(Con_ID) as con_count
FROM Tb_Consumer 
GROUP BY State) con
ON supp.State = con.State
WHERE supp_count > con_count
```